# How to print JSON data from console to webpage in React component

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, map-function

I have an array like this in React data file and I'm using the `.map()` method to load JSON data in component `ProjectItem.js`.

When I type `{console.log("title" + projects[0].title)}` and log data Projecttitle1 appears on console. How should I take the data, render that data on my web-app itself in functional component? (Projecttitle1 to show on the web-app)

**Data.json**

```
{
"projects": [
    {
        "title": "Projecttitle1",
        "category": "frontend development",
        "description": "",
        "desktop": [],
        "mobile": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**ProjectItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './ProjectItem.scss';
import useWindowWidth from '../../Hooks/useWindowWidth.js';
import { projects } from '../../data'

import desktopImage from '../../Assets/Images/Projects/Desktop/123.jpg';
import mobileImage from '../../Assets/Images/Projects/Mobile/123_square.jpg'


const ProjectItem = ({ viewProject }) => {

const imageUrl = useWindowWidth() >= 650 ? desktopImage : mobileImage;

const { windowWidth } = useWindowWidth();
return(
    <div className="projectItem" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${ imageUrl })`}}>
        {windowWidth >= 650 &&( 
            <>
            <div className="title">
                {projects.map((data, key)=>{
                        console.log(key);
                    return(
                        <div key={key}>
                        {data.title}
                        </div>
                    );
                })} 
            </div>
            <div className="viewProject">{viewProject}</div>
            </>
        )}  
    </div>
    );
}; 

export default ProjectItem
```

**Console:**

[image]

I've tried some attemps to import json file and then deconstruct from parsed json. Now when I run npm the data still isn't printing on web-app. Would there be possible solution to this?

**attempt1:**

```
import data from '../../data'

const { projects } =() => JSON.parse(data)
```

**attempt2:**

```
import data from '../../data'
const {projects} =() => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to deconstruct from json file which is basically a string representation of your object.
you need to import it, and then deconstruct from a parsed json
solution for this would be:

```
import data  from '../../data'
const { windowWidth } = useWindowWidth();
const { projects } = JSON.parse(data)
return(
<div className="projectItem" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${ imageUrl })`}}>
    {windowWidth >= 650 &&( 
        <>
        <div className="title">
            {projects.map((data, key)=>{
                    console.log(key);
                return(
                    <div key={key}>
                    {data.title}
                    </div>
                );
            })} 
        </div>
        <div className="viewProject">{viewProject}</div>
        </>
    )}  
</div>
);
```